Dynamic ComboBox with C# and ASPX ASP.NET Web Forms (ASPxDataEditors)
I am trying to create dynamic ComboBoxes, and the following code works for me:
private void controlCreateCmbT(string idcomp, string caption, List<dynamic> columns)
{
    var controlInfoCmbT = Session["controlInfoCmbT"] as List<controlInfoCmbT> ?? new List<controlInfoCmbT>();
    controlInfoCmbT.Add(new controlInfoCmbT { idComp = idcomp, caption = caption, columns = columns });
    Session["controlInfoCmbT"] = controlInfoCmbT;

    int numberOfColumns = 0;

    var comboBox = new ASPxComboBox
    {
        ID = idcomp,
        ClientInstanceName = idcomp,
        Theme = "Office365",
        Width = Unit.Percentage(50),
        NullText = caption,
        EnableCallbackMode = true,
        CallbackPageSize = 25,
        ValidationSettings = { CausesValidation = false },
        ValueType = typeof(string)
    };

    var firstRow = columns.FirstOrDefault();

    if (firstRow != null)
    {
        var properties = firstRow.GetType().GetProperties();
        numberOfColumns = properties.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            string propertyName = properties[i].Name; 

            var column = new ListBoxColumn(propertyName, "Column " + i);
            if (i == 0) 
            {
                comboBox.ValueField = propertyName;
            }

            comboBox.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        var formatString = string.Join(" | ", Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfColumns).Select(i => "{" + i + "}"));
        comboBox.TextFormatString = formatString;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The list is empty.");
    }

    var layoutItem = new LayoutItem
    {
        Caption = caption,
        ShowCaption = DefaultBoolean.True
    };
    var container = new LayoutItemNestedControlContainer();
    container.Controls.Add(comboBox);
    layoutItem.Controls.Add(container);
    formLayoutt.Items.Add(layoutItem);

    mConsulGen mcs = new mConsulGen();
    mcs.userLog = Session["usuario"].ToString();
    consulgen.GetPrueba(comboBox, mcs.userLog);
}

This is how I populate my ComboBoxes:
consulgen.GetPrueba(comboBox, mcs.userLog);

I pass the ComboBox to the controller that loads the data through a database query. However, when I have the ComboBox and scroll, it doesn't load more data, and I get the following error:
The target 'ctl00$PageContent$formLayoutt$incaIDPcal' for the callback could not be found or did not implement ICallbackEventHandler.
When I create a ComboBox statically, this issue does not occur.
The ComboBox is created here:
<dx:ASPxFormLayout runat="server" ID="formLayoutt" CssClass="formLayout" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <SettingsAdaptivity AdaptivityMode="SingleColumnWindowLimit" SwitchToSingleColumnAtWindowInnerWidth="700" />
    <Items>
        <dx:LayoutGroup ColCount="2" GroupBoxDecoration="None" UseDefaultPaddings="false" Paddings-PaddingTop="10">
            <GroupBoxStyle>
                <Caption Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="16" />
            </GroupBoxStyle>
            <Items>
            </Items>
        </dx:LayoutGroup>
    </Items>
</dx:ASPxFormLayout>`

I have tried using Page_Init in the following way:

`protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["controlInfoCmbT"] != null)
    {
        var controlInfoCmbT = (List<controlInfoCmbT>)Session["controlInfoCmbT"];
        var controlInfoCmbTCopy = new List<controlInfoCmbT>(controlInfoCmbT);

        if (IsCallback)
        {
            foreach (var info in controlInfoCmbTCopy)
            {
                if (!r)
                {
                    r = true;
                    controlCreateCmbT(info.idComp, info.caption, info.columns);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var info in controlInfoCmbTCopy)
        {
            if (!r)
            {
                formLayoutt.Items.Clear();
                controlCreateCmbT(info.idComp, info.caption, info.columns);
            }
        }
    }
}

If it enters the callback, it should rebuild the dynamic ComboBox once and load more data.
If the page is reloaded, it should reconstruct the ComboBoxes that were created previously.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
